# Media queries, Table cant be responsive?

Tags: css, responsive-design, html-table, media-queries

The webmaster tools says that the table TD,TH has 100% at 360px Screen and smaller, but it doesnt appear like that. Where is my problem? Thank you for advice. For test of the thing live, you can visit the website where I am trying to make it.
http://martinpodlesak.com/test4/
[image]
 my code:

```
<table id="hlstr">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h2>Agentura Martina Podleďešáka</2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                    <p>Vestibulum justo nibh, pharetra vitae commodo eget, hendrerit sed velit.</p>
                    <p>Vestibulum sapien orci, aliquet rhoncus lacus ac, rutrum laoreet nunc. </p>
                    <p> Mauris viverra luctus volutpat. Praesent erat sem, luctus ac ornare ut, molestie eu quam.</p>
            <td>
                <h2>Co děláme?</h2>
                   <p><a href="http://www.google.com/"></a><button class="button10"><a href="#">Úloha 1</a><p></p></button></p>
                   <p><a href="http://www.google.com/"></a><button class="button10"><a href="#">Úloha 2</a><p></p></button></p>
                   <p><a href="http://www.google.com/"></a><button class="button10"><a href="#">Úloha 3</a><p></p></button></p>
                   <p></p>
            </td>        
            <td> 
                <a class="twitter-timeline" data-lang="cs" data-width="315" data-height="300" href="https://twitter.com/podlesakmartin">Tweets by podlesakmartin</a> <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
            </td>
        </tr>


    </table>
```

CSS

```
    table#hlstr td, th
    {
      width: 30%;
    }
    table#hlstr h2 {
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    table#hlstr p {
    font-size: 12px;}
@media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {
    button.w3-button.demo {height: 29.3px;}
    table#hlstr td,th {width: 100%;}

}
```

Comment: This code is broken - unclosed tags - mistyped tags. #hlstr is about as bad as it gets as an id... no one but you will know what it means... and this is NOT table data. You are trying to use a table for layout and you just should not do that. If it's not a table of data... then you just do not use a table. It will be much easier if you use any of the other options to get your desired layout.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the markup is invalid.

Comment: As a web developer, DO NOT use tables for layout. Literally anything else is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely must use a table for layout... which is NEVER the case, then you'll have to tell the table to be `display: block;` instead of `display: table;` A table cell will try and maintain its form and allow ALL of the cells to fit. If you want to force it to behave differently, then you'll have to tell it not to be a table. Not just the table, but it's children. Sounds silly, right? That is because this would be a strange way to get the layout you are going for.

`<p><a href="http://www.google.com/"></a><button class="button10"><a href="#">Úloha 1</a><p></p></button></p>`

p > link with nothing... and a button w/ a link inside it and then another paragraph... I think this spot needs another look.

I urge you to think about it like this:

### markup

```
<section class='my-meaningfully-named-section'>

  <div class='some-copy'>
    <h2>Some copy</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p>Vestibulum justo nibh, pharetra vitae commodo eget, hendrerit sed velit.</p>
    <p>Vestibulum sapien orci, aliquet rhoncus lacus ac, rutrum laoreet nunc. </p>
    <p>Mauris viverra luctus volutpat. Praesent erat sem, luctus ac ornare ut, molestie eu quam.</p>
  </div>

  <div class='some-buttons'>
    <h2>Some buttons</h2>
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
    <button>Button 3</button>
  </div>

  <div class='twitter-stuff'>
    <h2>Twitter stuff</h2>
    <a class="twitter-timeline" data-lang="cs" data-width="315" data-height="300" href="https://twitter.com/podlesakmartin">Tweets by podlesakmartin</a><script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </div>

</section>
```

### styles

```
/* all the divs are already 100% width... because they are block-level elements */

.my-meaningfully-named-section .some-copy {
  background: red;
}
.my-meaningfully-named-section .some-buttons {
  background: lightblue;
}
.my-meaningfully-named-section .twitter-stuff {
  background: yellow;
}



@media (min-width: 600px) { /* break-point-1 */

  .my-meaningfully-named-section {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .my-meaningfully-named-section .some-copy {
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
  .my-meaningfully-named-section .some-buttons {
    flex-basis: 50%;
  }
  .my-meaningfully-named-section .twitter-stuff {
    flex-basis: 50%;
  }

}



@media (min-width: 900px) { /* break-point-2 */

  .my-meaningfully-named-section .some-copy {
    flex-basis: 30%;
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
  .my-meaningfully-named-section .some-buttons {
    flex-basis: auto;
  }
  .my-meaningfully-named-section .twitter-stuff {
    flex-basis: 300px;
  }

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/1h9051be/

Answer (score 0):

Tables are notoriously difficult to work with responsively, as they're not designed to scale. What I would recommend is switching the `display` of the table at smaller widths so that it is comprised of block-level elements:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {
  table, td, tr {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Using `display: block` will allow you to manipulate the tables content to your liking. The code above makes each row occupy 100% of the screen width at less than `360px`. Feel free to adjust the widths or even `float` them in order to modify the layout to your liking.

Note that in the following example I've modified the media query width to `700px` in order to demonstrate this in a snippet. Snippets also can't include Twitter timelines. For a **full** example in a resizable window, check out [**this JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/504u1oys/).

```css
table#hlstr td,
th {
  width: 30%;
}

table#hlstr h2 {
  font-size: 15px;
}

table#hlstr p {
  font-size: 12px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {
  button.w3-button.demo {
    height: 29.3px;
  }
  table#hlstr td,
  th {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/* New */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  table,
  td,
  tr {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="hlstr">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h2>Agentura Martina Podleďešáka</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      <p>Vestibulum justo nibh, pharetra vitae commodo eget, hendrerit sed velit.</p>
      <p>Vestibulum sapien orci, aliquet rhoncus lacus ac, rutrum laoreet nunc. </p>
      <p> Mauris viverra luctus volutpat. Praesent erat sem, luctus ac ornare ut, molestie eu quam.</p>
      <td>
        <h2>Co děláme?</h2>
        <p>
          <a href="http://www.google.com/"></a>
          <button class="button10"><a href="#">Úloha 1</a>
            <p></p>
          </button>
        </p>
        <p>
          <a href="http://www.google.com/"></a>
          <button class="button10"><a href="#">Úloha 2</a>
            <p></p>
          </button>
        </p>
        <p>
          <a href="http://www.google.com/"></a>
          <button class="button10"><a href="#">Úloha 3</a>
            <p></p>
          </button>
        </p>
        <p></p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a class="twitter-timeline" data-lang="cs" data-width="315" data-height="300" href="https://twitter.com/podlesakmartin">Tweets by podlesakmartin</a>
        <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: "as they're not designed to scale" - I 'm pretty sure that is their exact purpose.

Comment: It's impossible to 'break' the flow of a table and have one column sit below another with `display: table`. Sure, they'll scale down to the extent of having their columns shrink, but when you're dealing with `300px` and a table with multiple columns, there's only going to be about 1 letter per line in each column. It's far safer to simply change their `display` so that you can manipulate them easier. I opted to only do this at a breakpoint, so that the original table layout can be maintained on screens where it wouldn't be too narrow.